# UnrealScript - How to use the function "ClearTimer()"

Tags: timer, unrealscript

My current code: http://pastebin.com/3crQJqh8

But instead of using ClearAllTimers, I only want to clear one timer. But when I try to use the ClearTimer function specified here:

http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3:Actor_native_functions_%28UDK%29#ClearTimer

I get compilation errors. I belive that either I'm getting the syntax wrong or I'm missing some variable. I would greatly appreciate if someone could show me how to use the ClearTimer function.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it to work by using:

```
ClearTimer('ReplenishSprint');
```